# как можно сделать затемнённые и чёрные участки в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру на unity,проект в 2д и мне нужно чтоб затемнялись или были полностью черные те участки карты которые игрок не видит.Например игрок повернулся налево и сдвинулся вниз,камера сместилась налево и вниз,сверху затемненные и черные участки тоесть переход от нормальных к полностью не видимым(чёрным) или например если перед ним стена он видит только то что перед ним и затемненные участки по бокам или по простому только те которые в поле зрения.Использую Tilemap.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то что ты ищешь называется field of view, есть множество способов реализации - простые на рейкасте, сложные  использованием stencil buffer

Comment: можно поподробнее

Comment: Не думаю что здесь разрешено постить ссылки на сторонние ресурсы. В гугле и ютубе найдешь кучу уроков на эту тему по названию выше

Comment: @Lexanom Ссылки - это замечательно.

Comment: @Lexanom ccылки допустимы в том случае если ответ является полноценным и без ссылки. Например, ты копируешь весь код, который решает проблему и указываешь источник. Если ответ содержит исключительно ссылку - это запрещено, потому что ссылка имеет свойство устаревать и со временем она может отвалится по той или иной причине.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой и глупый способ - это повесить внутрь игрока спрайт который делает то что тебе нужно. То есть большое черное пятно + треугольник сделанный альфа-каналом.

Когда ты будешь поворачивать игрока спрайт будет поворачиваться вместе с ним. Ничего сложного. Если необходимо плавность перехода из видимого до затемненного обзора - это просто меняется в изображении в том же фотошопе.

Черный цвет на картинке должен покрывать всю площадь обзора камеры которая находится на сцене сверху) https://i.stack.imgur.com/scNIW.png

Этот способ обычно использовался в флеш-играх и разного рода старых 2д шутерах с видом сверху.

---

Если же необходим продвинутый вариант - когда обьекты на которые ты смотришь "закрывают" обьекты позади их

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно в гугле поискать видеоуроки:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQG9aUWarwE

И готовые репозитории, например:

- https://github.com/Kellojo/Unity---Field-of-View-Fog-of-War
- https://github.com/SebLague/Field-of-View (этот должен быть по-лучше, как раз со видеоуроков по скриншоту выше)