# Как проверить возможно ли теоретически увидеть объект из конкретной точки

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру в которой нужно делать рандомные темные коридоры, к примеру:
[image]

Сделал код в котором определяю рандомную позицию потом затемняю клон материала в зависмости от расстояния.

```
GameObject[] gameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Map"); // получаем все стены, полы, и потолки
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Vector3 vector = wanderer.GetNewTargetHallway() + new Vector3(0,5,0);// получаем случайную позицию
    foreach (GameObject gameObject in gameObjects)
    {
        MeshRenderer meshRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        if (Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, vector) < 25f)
        {
            meshRenderer.material = Instantiate<Material>(meshRenderer.material); // клонируем материал
            meshRenderer.material.color = Color.white * (Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, vector) / 25); // затемняем матерал в зависимости от расстояния 
        }
    }
}
```

В общем получилось неплохо:
[image]

Однако, затемнение срабатывает через стены, что выглядит не очень:
[image]

Как проверить возможно ли теоретически увидеть объект из конкретной точки?

Comment: Вроде в Unity куча инструментов для работы с освещением.

Comment: @aepot освещение в принципе довольно ресурсоемкая штука. Так что учитывая допотопную графику могу предположить что это своего рода оптимизация

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое понятие как Шейдер (Shader). Он отрисовывает текстуру поверх меша (поверхности).

Обычно ради оптимизации шейдеры являются "односторонними" - т.е. там отрисовывается одна текстура на обе плоскости полигона или вообще только на одну, а вторая плоскость является прозрачной.

Тебе необходимо использовать двухсторонний шейдер на твои стены и тогда ты сможешь задать текстуру на каждую отдельную сторону. Или же сделать обьемные стены и менять затемнение текстуры только куска.

Для того что бы найти примеры как стандартные так и кастомные ты можешь ввести в гугле "unity double sided shader"

и в том числе найти подобный на ассет сторе:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/free-double-sided-shaders-23087

---

Теперь по поводу вопроса "Есть какой-нибудь способ проверить видно ли объект из конкретной точки?"

Я бы советовал обратиться к документации по методу

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().isVisible
```

Или же обратиться к вот этому вопросу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1321860/186752

Возможно там чего интересного найдешь

Comment: Я имел в виду не видит ли камера объект, а вообще возможно ли теоретически увидеть объект из конкретной точки. Еще имеется в виду что это не проблема с шейдером, а с тем что скрипт просто затемняет все объекты рядом, даже если он находится за стенкой

Comment: смотри ссылку, там этот вопрос решается